# How to add a CSS class with animation to the border of a table's cells?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to add a blinking effect to my table when a button is pressed. My code kind of achieves this by making the whole table blink however it makes the data in the cells without an existing css hard to read. Therefore, I am trying to figure out if it is possible to make the just the border of each cell have the blinking effect instead of the whole cell so that the data is still easily readable as seen in the status row. Is this possible without having to add a css to every single cell?

```js
$("#alarm").click(function() {
  $("#tableContainer").addClass("blink");
  $("#tableContainer").addClass("blink");
});

$("#stopAlarm").click(function() {
  $("#tableContainer").removeClass("blink");
  $("#tableContainer").removeClass("blink");
});
```

```css
.heading {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #C1C1C1;
}

.monitor {
  text-align: center;
}

.row {
  text-align: right;
  background-color: powderblue;
}

div {
  align-content: center;
}

th,
td {
  min-width: 80px;
  width: auto;
  text-align: center;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #F1F1F1;
}

.blink {
  animation: blink 200ms infinite alternate;
}


/*blink effect color switcher*/

@keyframes blink {
  from {
    background-color: white;
  }
  to {
    background-color: red;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <table id="tableContainer">
    <tr>
      <th class="heading">dsgegaw</th>
      <th class="heading">fvsegwaf</th>
      <th class="heading">peaagwwa</th>
      <th class="heading">p76uihx</th>
      <th class="heading">gdjhrdu3</th>
      <th class="heading">sg45y7ids</th>
      <th class="heading">30jqnfj</th>
      <th class="heading">][2proq2=0-i</th>
      <th class="heading">-20=riojwkfl</th>
      <th class="heading">t-09tujkjgf</th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td class="column"></td>
      <td class="monitor"></td>
      <td class="monitor"></td>
      <td class="monitor"></td>
      <td class="monitor"></td>
      <td class="monitor"></td>
      <td class="monitor"></td>
      <td class="monitor"></td>
      <td class="monitor"></td>
      <td class="monitor"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td class="row">System Time</td>
      <td>
        <div id="p1">hrgfawf</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div id="p11">waffejtj</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div id="c1">awfwhr</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div id="ca1">afcascwef</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div id="m1">grthrh</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div id="mp1"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td class="row">Status</td>
      <td>
        <div id="p2">awegrthrth</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div id="p21">DFAWFERGE</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div id="c2">5687w43t</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div id="ca2">fq3t34ytg5</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div id="m2">oik768yq3</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div id="mp2">90['97t</div>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td class="row">Logged Time</td>
      <td>
        <div id="p3">4t3twfe6u</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div id="p31">76i4y3t3</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div id="c3">vetg34wt43</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>


  <button id="alarm" type="button">Start Alarm</button>
  <button id="stopAlarm" type="button">Stop Alarm</button>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this you first need to put borders on the `th` and `td` elements. Then you can amend the `.blink` selector to amend the colours of the border, instead of the background, like this:

```js
$("#alarm").click(function() {
  $("#tableContainer").addClass("blink");
});

$("#stopAlarm").click(function() {
  $("#tableContainer").removeClass("blink");
});
```

```css
.heading {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #C1C1C1;
}

.monitor {
  text-align: center;
}

.row {
  text-align: right;
  background-color: powderblue;
}

div {
  align-content: center;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

th,
td {
  min-width: 80px;
  width: auto;
  text-align: center;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  border: 2px solid #FFF;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #F1F1F1;
}

.blink th, 
.blink td {
  animation: blink 200ms infinite alternate;
}


/*blink effect color switcher*/

@keyframes blink {
  from {
    border-color: white;
  }
  to {
    border-color: red;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="tableContainer">
  <tr>
    <th class="heading">dsgegaw</th>
    <th class="heading">fvsegwaf</th>
    <th class="heading">peaagwwa</th>
    <th class="heading">p76uihx</th>
    <th class="heading">gdjhrdu3</th>
    <th class="heading">sg45y7ids</th>
    <th class="heading">30jqnfj</th>
    <th class="heading">][2proq2=0-i</th>
    <th class="heading">-20=riojwkfl</th>
    <th class="heading">t-09tujkjgf</th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td class="column"></td>
    <td class="monitor"></td>
    <td class="monitor"></td>
    <td class="monitor"></td>
    <td class="monitor"></td>
    <td class="monitor"></td>
    <td class="monitor"></td>
    <td class="monitor"></td>
    <td class="monitor"></td>
    <td class="monitor"></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td class="row">System Time</td>
    <td>
      <div id="p1">hrgfawf</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div id="p11">waffejtj</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div id="c1">awfwhr</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div id="ca1">afcascwef</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div id="m1">grthrh</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div id="mp1"></div>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td class="row">Status</td>
    <td>
      <div id="p2">awegrthrth</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div id="p21">DFAWFERGE</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div id="c2">5687w43t</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div id="ca2">fq3t34ytg5</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div id="m2">oik768yq3</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div id="mp2">90['97t</div>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td class="row">Logged Time</td>
    <td>
      <div id="p3">4t3twfe6u</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div id="p31">76i4y3t3</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div id="c3">vetg34wt43</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>


<button id="alarm" type="button">Start Alarm</button>
<button id="stopAlarm" type="button">Stop Alarm</button>
```